# cant display image from database outside of table in php

Tags: php, html

I have this code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET["cmd"]))
  $cmd = $_GET["cmd"];
else
  die("You should have a 'cmd' parameter in your URL");
 $pk = $_GET["pk"];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","geheim");
if(!$con)
{
die('Connection failed because of' .mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("ebay",$con);
if($cmd=="GetAuctionData")
{
echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";
$sql="SELECT * FROM Auctions WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row['USERNAME']."</td>
<td>".$row['ARTICLE_NO']."</td>
<td>".$row['ARTICLE_NAME']."</td>
<td>".$row['SUBTITLE']."</td>
<td>".$row['CURRENT_BID']."</td>
<td>".$row['START_PRICE']."</td>
<td>".$row['BID_COUNT']."</td>
<td>".$row['QUANT_TOTAL']."</td>
<td>".$row['QUANT_SOLD']."</td>
<td>".$row['ACCESSSTARTS']."</td>
<td>".$row['ACCESSENDS']."</td>
<td>".$row['ACCESSORIGIN_END']."</td>
<td>".$row['USERNAME']."</td>
<td>".$row['BEST_BIDDER_ID']."</td>
<td>".$row['FINISHED']."</td>
<td>".$row['WATCH']."</td>
<td>".$row['BUYITNOW_PRICE']."</td>
<td>".$row['PIC_URL']."</td>
<td>".$row['PRIVATE_AUCTION']."</td>
<td>".$row['AUCTION_TYPE']."</td>
<td>".$row['ACCESSINSERT_DATE']."</td>
<td>".$row['ACCESSUPDATE_DATE']."</td>
<td>".$row['CAT_1_ID']."</td>
<td>".$row['CAT_2_ID']."</td>
<td>".$row['ARTICLE_DESC']."</td>
<td>".$row['COUNTRYCODE']."</td>
<td>".$row['LOCATION']."</td>
<td>".$row['CONDITIONS']."</td>
<td>".$row['REVISED']."</td>
<td>".$row['PAYPAL_ACCEPT']."</td>
<td>".$row['PRE_TERMINATED']."</td>
<td>".$row['SHIPPING_TO']."</td>
<td>".$row['FEE_INSERTION']."</td>
<td>".$row['FEE_FINAL']."</td>
<td>".$row['FEE_LISTING']."</td>
<td>".$row['PIC_XXL']."</td>
<td>".$row['PIC_DIASHOW']."</td>
<td>".$row['PIC_COUNT']."</td>
<td>".$row['ITEM_SITE_ID']."</td>
<td>".$row['STARTS']."</td>
<td>".$row['ENDS']."</td>
<td>".$row['ORIGIN_END']."</td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
echo "<img src=".$row['PIC_URL'].">";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the generated html:

```
<table border='1' width='100%'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr><tr>
<td>fashionticker1</td>
<td>220288560247</td>
<td>Ed Hardy Herren Shirt Rock & Roll Weiss XXL Neu & OVP</td>
<td></td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>49.00</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1.10.2008 16:22:09</td>
<td>6.10.2008 16:22:09</td>
<td>6.10.2008 16:22:09</td>
<td>fashionticker1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>59.00</td>
<td>http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/ebay2/10/49/76/10497654/13895964e.jpg</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>6.10.2008 16:21:47</td>
<td>6.10.2008 16:28:31</td>
<td>32315</td>
<td>0</td>
<td><!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Bitte ändern Sie im eigenen Interesse nichts an diesem Code! ++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Das kann massive Fehldarstellungen ihrer Auktion zur Folge haben! +++++++++++++++++++ -->
<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Ihr Supreme Team +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
</td>
<td>
<br>
<br>
<style ty</td>
<td>float: right;
</td>
<td>margin: 0px;
</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>padding:5px; 
</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>font-size: 12px;
</td>
<td>color: #333333;
}
#h</td>
<td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
<td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
<td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr></table><img src=>
```

Whatever I do, I can not get an image to display, and when PIC_URL is empty, it only displays a placeholder image above the table, and I want it below.

Comment: Could you include the HTML that's output?  It sounds like you're missing a tag or a quote somewhere.

Comment: I'd be more interested in the full content of the code blocks.
We're missing the opening curly braces and with only what we're seeing, it's entirely possible that the $row variable fell out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
echo "<img src=\"".$row['PIC_URL']."\">";
```

Comment: can you paste the HTML? I'll guess either the HTML is incorrect or the image doesn't exist on the given URL

Comment: The image definitely exists, I have pasted the html here: http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22292

Answer (score 1):

`<style ty</td>` looks like the problem to me.

Comment: that is not my doing, but part of the data that contains html markup. Why would it be preventing an image from showing if the image is outsideof the database?

Comment: This is correct - the browser (tested in FF) seems to ignore the rest of the html as the tag is not closed. Maybe you can call strip_tags() or htmlentities() on that bad html data.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating that img tag *outside* of your while loop, which ends when $row is false. In other words, you'll only reach that code when $row doesn't contain any information because you've finished reading rows!

Either output a cell for the image, or output a new row with a single cell for the image spanning the entire row.

Comment: if i leave it in the loop nothing is displayed still

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
*snip*
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<img src=".$row['PIC_URL'].">";
```

Because the loop finished, $row is false. You need to change it to something like.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
*snip*
$lastImg = $row['PIC_URL'];
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<img src=\"$lastImg\">";
```

Im starting to doubt you have a valid PIC_URL returned by yer database query. You should try this, see if you get any valid pictures from the url's, and especially if the last url in the list is valid.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    *snip*
    $images[] = $row['PIC_URL'];
}
echo "</table>";
?><p>Are these valid urls you can open in yer browser?</p><pre><?php
    print_r($images);
?></pre><?php
```

Comment: Still no image is displayed, although it generates correct html and there is definitely an image at the url

Comment: You have to check:
is there an attribute called PIC_URL returned with the query?
does the last row in your query have a valid picture?
does the url work if you put it in a browser?

Comment: The html is correct, and when I take the image url that is generated in the html it works fine,PIC_URL is returned with the query, I have changed to layers from a table but the problem is the same.